# Windows Explorer - Copy a file and increase the number by 1

Tags: windows, rename, file-rename, explorer

I'm currently working on a project where I'm creating a large number of files which are similar to an original file. So far in Windows Explorer I'm having to copy and paste the original file in to the same folder and then rename the copy.

However, my files are named 
File 1 Summary, File 2 Summary, File 3 Summary etc 
but Windows renames the copies File 1 Summary_Copy. Therefore I have to delete the string at the end and rev the number of the file manually.

Is there any way to change this setting in Windows or are there any work arounds (file managing programs or scripts) that can solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So I found the best way was to create a batch file. The batch file took the file I wanted to copy and renamed it using user defined strings.

Here's the batch file:

```
@echo off
set /p id="Filename:"
set /p new="New File Prefix:"
set /p num="Enter number of copies:"
for /l %%x in (1,1,%num%) do 
    (copy "%id%.xml" %new%%%x" Summary.xml")
```

So this batch file asks for the filename( I knew I was dealing with xml files so that's why it doesn't take into account the file extension). Then it asks for the new files prefix and the number of copies I want to make.

The FOR loop starts at 1 and steps by 1 until it reaches the required copy amount. The for loop executes the copy command and renames the file 
{Prefix}{Loop Number} Summary.xml

I hope this helps